# Net Core: Enforce Required Class Members in Request API Automatically, for Not Null Data Types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, data-annotations

We have API Controller which obtains Product Data with Request Dto. To make class member required, we need to place `Required` Attribute in the Dto. Otherwise service can execute with empty member.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Currently have Request DTO with 20+ members, and writing `[Required]` in all class members seems very repetitive.

My question is, why is RequiredAttribute necessary? We already have int and nullable members. Shouldn't data types themselves enforce the contract?

And Is there a way to automate and have class members enforce Required, without writing everywhere ?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ProductResponse>> GetProductData(BaseRequest<ProductRequestDto> request)
{
    var response = await _productService.GetProductItem(request);
    return Ok(response);


public class ProductRequestDto
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
    public int BarCodeNumber{ get; set; }
    ....
```

[How to add custom error message with “required” htmlattribute to mvc 5 razor view text input editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485898/how-to-add-custom-error-message-with-required-htmlattribute-to-mvc-5-razor-vie)

```
public class ProductRequestDto
{
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Available { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int BarCodeNumber{ get; set; }
    ....
```

Comment: You can add your own convention binding / validation metadata via `.AddMvc(o => o.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(...` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.modelmetadatadetailsproviders?view=aspnetcore-3.1), but I'm not sure how to turn that into a good answer....

Comment: The `[Required]` attribute works with only nullable types. If you want to make sure that data for value types is present you may use the `[BindRequired]` attribute for them.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing - the title doesn't reflect the body. Besides, from .net core 3.0 non-nullable type properties are automatically considered having an implicit Required attribute?

Comment: hi @atiyar can you show the resource saying all non-nullable are automatically have implicit Required? we were just testing in Net core 3.1, and were able to pass through with a missing class member in swagger/postman

Comment: @marksmith542 There you go - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#required-attribute

Comment: hi @atiyar strange, I dont have SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes  anywhere in my program, I went to postman, totally removed a non-nullable class member from my json Object Data Request, and API is still trying to go through, using Net Core 3.1

Comment: You can write a custom ModelBinder and use it once for a class.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using 
[Fluent Validation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) you can do something like this:

This validator can validate any dto using reflection

Validator:

```
using FluentValidation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleTests
{
    public class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<ModelDTO>
    {
        public MyValidator()
        {
            foreach (var item in typeof(ModelDTO).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Name}, Type: {item.PropertyType}");

                if (item.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                {
                    RuleFor(x => (int)item.GetValue(x, null)).NotEmpty<ModelDTO,int>();
                }
                else
                {
                    RuleFor(x => (string)item.GetValue(x, null)).NotEmpty<ModelDTO, string>();
                }
            //Other stuff...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `NotEmpty` refuses null and default values.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                ModelDTO modelDTO = new ModelDTO
                {
                    MyProperty1 = null, //string
                    MyProperty2 = 0, //int
                    MyProperty3 = null, //string
                    MyProperty4 = 0 //int
                };

                MyValidator validationRules = new MyValidator();
                FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult result = validationRules.Validate(modelDTO);

                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Name: MyProperty1, Type: System.String
> Name: MyProperty2, Type: System.Int32
> Name: MyProperty3, Type: System.String
> Name: MyProperty4, Type: System.Int32
> must not be empty.
> must not be empty.
> must not be empty.
> must not be empty.
> Done!

And for a more complete solution:
See this SO question [how-to-use-reflection-in-fluentvalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871741/how-to-use-reflection-in-fluentvalidation).

It uses the same concept, the validator takes a `PropertyInfo` and does its validation by getting the type and value.

The below code is from the mentioned question.

Property Validator:

```
public class CustomNotEmpty<T> : PropertyValidator
{
    private PropertyInfo _propertyInfo;

    public CustomNotEmpty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        : base(string.Format("{0} is required", propertyInfo.Name))
    {
        _propertyInfo = propertyInfo;
    }

    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
        return !IsNullOrEmpty(_propertyInfo, (T)context.Instance);
    }

    private bool IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyInfo property, T obj)
    {
        var t = property.PropertyType;
        var v = property.GetValue(obj);

        // Omitted for clarity...
    }
}
```

Rule Builder:

```
public static class ValidatorExtensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, T> CustomNotEmpty<T>(
        this IRuleBuilder<T, T> ruleBuilder, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new CustomNotEmpty<T>(propertyInfo));
    }
}
```

And finally the validator:

```
public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<Foo>
{
    public FooValidator(Foo obj)
    {
        // Iterate properties using reflection
        var properties = ReflectionHelper.GetShallowPropertiesInfo(obj);//This is a custom helper that retrieves the type properties.
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            // Create rule for each property, based on some data coming from other service...
            RuleFor(o => o)
                .CustomNotEmpty(obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name))
                .When(o =>
            {
                return true; // do other stuff...
            });
        }
    }
}
```